# Sql script ran ok in 3.0.2 but not in orientdb 3.0.3 (using console.sh)

Tags: orientdb

With orientdb 3.0.2 I can run this script just fine using console.sh :

```
connect remote:localhost/mydatabase root mypassword;
script sql
begin;
INSERT INTO ....blah blah blah...
commit;
end
```

But, with orient 3.0.3 it just does not run. I get this error: *"begin " unexpected*.  I will go back to work with orientdb 3.0.2.

Maybe there is a new way of doing scripts in 3.0.3?

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing semicolon right after `script sql`:

```
connect remote:localhost/mydatabase root mypassword;
script sql;
begin;
INSERT INTO ... ;
commit;
end
```